# Where have I seen this logo?

Tags: vector, logo, images, copyright

I just started concepting logos for a company created this. It seems very similar to something I've seen before and can not seem to figure out where it's from. Any ideas? I'm basically talking about the leaf / teardrop shape being used an the I's dot.

Thank you! Hope this question is relevant for the site.[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Truvia; Tropicana; 50% of all tea logos; laxative logos

The problem is that the shape itself is very simple and recognizable and therefore easy to map onto other logos. Bear in mind some big companies sue over the use of green, so...